# Why is this `even` function using getElementById not working?

Tags: javascript, html

Can someone help me out with `document.getElementById`?

```
function even()
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
      alert(i);
    }
  }

  document.getElementById("even").innerHTML = i + '<br>';
}
```

Comment: Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors.

Comment: "Not working" isn't enough. What happens? What doesn't happen? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: you need to tell people what is actually wrong, what is the expected result? what are you actually getting ? Don't make people guess what your problem is.

Answer (score -1):

You may be running your function before the DOM is fully loaded and the element that are trying to get will not be there. You should run your function when the DOM is ready.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
 even();
});
```

Also, you are attempting to use the value of the variable `i` outside of the `for` loop (it will be undefined). You have a few syntax errors with your code as well. You do not have the opening and closing parentheses for your function.

```js
function even(){
for(i=0;i<10;i++){ 
if (i%2 == 0){
alert(i);
document.getElementById("even").innerHTML = i + ' ';
}
} 
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  even();
});
```

```html
<span id="even"></span>
```

Answer (score -1):

The really easy way to check is drop your code into debug console in browser (ctrl+shift+c in chrome, then console tab, paste your js, press enter). If its' working this way it means that as hev1 said above, you're trying to access it before it gets loaded/created.